# Connecting to MYSQL on an EC2 instance

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use Zapier to connect to our MySQL database in order to add results from forms (hosting with WordPress) directly into our internal database.

The database is working properly and so are the forms but when I try to establish a connection to the database with Zapier I just get a timeout error.

I've spoken to Zapier about it and they've said that something is blocking them from being able to talk to our database and that I just need to ssh into the box that has the mysql client installed. I know I'm probably being very dumb but I don't understand what they mean. I asked them to clarify and they suggested I tried `mysql --connect_timeout 5 -u zapper -p xxxxxxxxxxx` I tried to connect to what I thought was the instance using `ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws.pem -p 1903 ubuntu@12.34.5.678` (I can do that without a problem) and then tried `mysql --connect_timeout 5 -u zapper -p xxxxxxxxxxx`

That gave me an error saying:

> Warning: Using unique option prefix pass instead of password is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
>
> Enter password:

I tried my admin password, the MySQL password, the password for the zapper user as well as the sftp password but none of them work. It just says:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'zapier'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I'd be grateful for any help on this please.

**EDIT:**

I think I might have been able to connect. I tried changing -p to password and the got this:

> Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
>   owners.
>
> Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
>     -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
>     -I, --help          Synonym for -?
>     --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
>                         'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
>                         and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
>                         --disable-auto-rehash.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
>     -A, --no-auto-rehash 
>                         No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
>                         table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
>                         mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
>     --auto-vertical-output 
>                         Automatically switch to vertical output mode if the
>                         result is wider than the terminal width.
>     -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
>                         (Enables --silent.)
>     --character-sets-dir=name 
>                         Directory for character set files.
>     --column-type-info  Display column type information.
>     -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
>                         default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
>                         with --comments.
>     -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.
>     -#, --debug[=#]     This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.
>     --debug-check       Check memory and open file usage at exit.
>     -T, --debug-info    Print some debug info at exit.
>     -D, --database=name Database to use.
>     --default-character-set=name 
>                         Set the default character set.
>     --delimiter=name    Delimiter to be used.
>     --enable-cleartext-plugin 
>                         Enable/disable the clear text authentication plugin.
>     -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history
>                         file.)
>     -E, --vertical      Print the output of a query (rows) vertically.
>     -f, --force         Continue even if we get an SQL error.
>     -G, --named-commands 
>                         Enable named commands. Named commands mean this program's
>                         internal commands; see mysql> help . When enabled, the
>                         named commands can be used from any line of the query,
>                         otherwise only from the first line, before an enter.
>                         Disable with --disable-named-commands. This option is
>                         disabled by default.
>     -i, --ignore-spaces Ignore space after function names.
>     --init-command=name SQL Command to execute when connecting to MySQL server.
>                         Will automatically be re-executed when reconnecting.
>     --local-infile      Enable/disable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.
>     -b, --no-beep       Turn off beep on error.
>     -h, --host=name     Connect to host.
>     -H, --html          Produce HTML output.
>     -X, --xml           Produce XML output.
>     --line-numbers      Write line numbers for errors.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-line-numbers to disable.)
>     -L, --skip-line-numbers 
>                         Don't write line number for errors.
>     -n, --unbuffered    Flush buffer after each query.
>     --column-names      Write column names in results.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-column-names to disable.)
>     -N, --skip-column-names 
>                         Don't write column names in results.
>     --sigint-ignore     Ignore SIGINT (CTRL-C).
>     -o, --one-database  Ignore statements except those that occur while the
>                         default database is the one named at the command line.
>     --pager[=name]      Pager to use to display results. If you don't supply an
>                         option, the default pager is taken from your ENV variable
>                         PAGER. Valid pagers are less, more, cat [> filename],
>                         etc. See interactive help (\h) also. This option does not
>                         work in batch mode. Disable with --disable-pager. This
>                         option is disabled by default.
>     -p, --password[=name] 
>                         Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
>                         not given it's asked from the tty.
>     -P, --port=#        Port number to use for connection or 0 for default to, in
>                         order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
>                         /etc/services, built-in default (3306).
>     --prompt=name       Set the mysql prompt to this value.
>     --protocol=name     The protocol to use for connection (tcp, socket, pipe,
>                         memory).
>     -q, --quick         Don't cache result, print it row by row. This may slow
>                         down the server if the output is suspended. Doesn't use
>                         history file.
>     -r, --raw           Write fields without conversion. Used with --batch.
>     --reconnect         Reconnect if the connection is lost. Disable with
>                         --disable-reconnect. This option is enabled by default.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-reconnect to disable.)
>     -s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a tab as separator,
>                         each row on new line.
>     -S, --socket=name   The socket file to use for connection.
>     --ssl               Enable SSL for connection (automatically enabled with
>                         other flags).
>     --ssl-ca=name       CA file in PEM format (check OpenSSL docs, implies
>                         --ssl).
>     --ssl-capath=name   CA directory (check OpenSSL docs, implies --ssl).
>     --ssl-cert=name     X509 cert in PEM format (implies --ssl).
>     --ssl-cipher=name   SSL cipher to use (implies --ssl).
>     --ssl-key=name      X509 key in PEM format (implies --ssl).
>     --ssl-verify-server-cert 
>                         Verify server's "Common Name" in its cert against
>                         hostname used when connecting. This option is disabled by
>                         default.
>     -t, --table         Output in table format.
>     --tee=name          Append everything into outfile. See interactive help (\h)
>                         also. Does not work in batch mode. Disable with
>                         --disable-tee. This option is disabled by default.
>     -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.
>     -U, --safe-updates  Only allow UPDATE and DELETE that uses keys.
>     -U, --i-am-a-dummy  Synonym for option --safe-updates, -U.
>     -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).
>     -V, --version       Output version information and exit.
>     -w, --wait          Wait and retry if connection is down.
>     --connect-timeout=# Number of seconds before connection timeout.
>     --max-allowed-packet=# 
>                         The maximum packet length to send to or receive from
>                         server.
>     --net-buffer-length=# 
>                         The buffer size for TCP/IP and socket communication.
>     --select-limit=#    Automatic limit for SELECT when using --safe-updates.
>     --max-join-size=#   Automatic limit for rows in a join when using
>                         --safe-updates.
>     --secure-auth       Refuse client connecting to server if it uses old
>                         (pre-4.1.1) protocol.
>     --server-arg=name   Send embedded server this as a parameter.
>     --show-warnings     Show warnings after every statement.
>     --plugin-dir=name   Directory for client-side plugins.
>     --default-auth=name Default authentication client-side plugin to use.
>
> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
>   /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
>   The following groups are read: mysql client
>   The following options may be given as the first argument:
>   --print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
>   --no-defaults           Don't read default options from any option file.
>   --defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.
>   --defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read.
>
> Variables (--variable-name=value)
>   and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
>
> ---
>
> auto-rehash                       TRUE
>   auto-vertical-output              FALSE
>   character-sets-dir                (No default value)
>   column-type-info                  FALSE
>   comments                          FALSE
>   compress                          FALSE
>   debug-check                       FALSE
>   debug-info                        FALSE
>   database                          mycroft
>   default-character-set             auto
>   delimiter                         ;
>   enable-cleartext-plugin           FALSE
>   vertical                          FALSE
>   force                             FALSE
>   named-commands                    FALSE
>   ignore-spaces                     FALSE
>   init-command                      (No default value)
>   local-infile                      FALSE
>   no-beep                           FALSE
>   host                              (No default value)
>   html                              FALSE
>   xml                               FALSE
>   line-numbers                      TRUE
>   unbuffered                        FALSE
>   column-names                      TRUE
>   sigint-ignore                     FALSE
>   port                              3306
>   prompt                            mysql> 
>   quick                             FALSE
>   raw                               FALSE
>   reconnect                         TRUE
>   socket                            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>   ssl                               FALSE
>   ssl-ca                            (No default value)
>   ssl-capath                        (No default value)
>   ssl-cert                          (No default value)
>   ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
>   ssl-key                           (No default value)
>   ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE
>   table                             FALSE
>   user                              zapier_connect
>   safe-updates                      FALSE
>   i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE
>   connect-timeout                   5
>   max-allowed-packet                16777216
>   net-buffer-length                 16384
>   select-limit                      1000
>   max-join-size                     1000000
>   secure-auth                       FALSE
>   show-warnings                     FALSE
>   plugin-dir                        (No default value)
>   default-auth                      (No default value)

Does that mean I've managed to connect? If it does then Zapier said that means it's something to do with the instance or AWS security as to why it won't connect. I've never used AWS before so don't know exactly what this means.

Comment: Might help - if you're entering the password as part of the command there shouldn't be a gap between the `-p` and the password itself e.g.`mysql -u Username -pMyPassword`. Better to just have the `-p` and enter the password when prompted though.

Comment: Thanks @georgeb_dba I managed to connect using `mysql --connect_timeout 5 -u zapper password xxxxxxxxxxx` in the end but I still can't connect to it with Zapier

Comment: Is it "zapier" or "zapper"? You have spelled it both ways several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Zapier is coming in from outside your instance, a possible cause of your problem is the [security group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) for your instance.  Most ports on EC2 instances (except the SSH port) are normally blocked by default unless you explicitly open them.

So you would need to open the mysql port 3306 on your instance up to the ip address Zapier is coming in from.  (preferably you would not open it up to everyone in the world.)

See [Using Amazon RDS/EC2](https://zapier.com/help/mysql/#cant-connect-my-database) on the Zapier site, starting from the section where it says **Can't Connect to My Database**.  They continue on to provide specific instructions for the security group settings.

You will also probably need to grant permission on the database using the mysql GRANT command to the user coming in from the Zapier ip address.

Something like this should work :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON mydb.*
TO 'user'@'54.86.9.50'
IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

Or you can allow that user to come in from any ip adress like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON mydb.*
TO 'user'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

(Incoming requests would still be limited to Zapier ip addresses due to the security group settings.)

Comment: Thanks, I've now opened up the port for their IP addresses but now I get this error: authorisation failed: (OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '12.34.5.678' (111)") None None

Comment: You'll probably also have to grant rights in mysql to that user coming in from the new ip addresses. Currently it is probably only allowing incoming requests from localhost.  I edited my response to include this info.  The Zapier site does reference this by referring back to this tackexchange link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address

Comment: I did check that, it's got all privileges and grant rights to everything

Comment: Okay I looked up that error and it seems your mysql server may be configured to only listen on the local host.  See if this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472175/operationalerror-operationalerror-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-1

Comment: I followed that and changed the bind-address then restarted the mysql. It wouldn't start. I used this **sudo service mysql restart** to restart it now all I get is **stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start
ubuntu@ip-123-45-67-890:~$** Have I done something wrong? I put the bind-address back to what it was then was able to restart

Comment: I tried commenting out the bind-address but then Zapier gave me this error: **authorization failed: (OperationalError) (1130, "Host 'ec2-123-45-67-890.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server") None None**